# How do I reference this link table in another entity?

Tags: database-design

I have the entities Organization and Question. Organization_Question is a link table between the two entities with a Primary key that is the two foreign keys organization_id and question_id.

What If I want to reference this in another entity?

Say the organization has many employees whom need access to these Organization_Questions. How would I reference this link table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `organization_id, question_id` pair the same way you would use a single id column, i.e. you can include the columns in other tables and set up composite foreign key constraints.

For example, you could make a "link table" with columns `employee_id, organization_id, question_id`.